# Deleting Non-ASCII *lines* from a file?

Tags: python, linux, string, file, ascii

Is there a way I can remove non-ascii lines (not characters) from a file? So given something like this:

```
Line 1 (full ASCII character set)
Line 2 (contains unicode characters)
Line 3 (full ASCII)
Line 4 (contains unicode characters)
```

I want:

```
Line 1
Line 3
```

I know I can use `iconv` to remove ASCII characters but I want to delete any line that contains non-ascii lines. Is there a utility/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: When you say "full ASCII character set", do you mean that it includes every byte value from 0 to 127? So the line can contain deletes, vertical-tabs, form-feeds, null bytes, and so on, as long as none of its bytes is 128 or higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to eliminate lines that contain any non-ascii characters:

```
def ascii_lines(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        if all(ord(ch) < 128 for ch in line):
            yield line

f = open('somefile.txt')
for line in ascii_lines(f):
    print line
```

Answer (score 3):

Given string like the next:

```
>>> s = "asd\n\xaa\xfa\xaf\nqwe"
>>> print s
asd
╙З╞
qwe
```

You may simply filter it by your criteria:

```
>>> s = filter(lambda x: ord(x) < 128, s)
>>> s
'asd\n\nqwe'
>>> print s
asd

qwe
```

Also you may achieve the same result with converting to `unicode`:

```
>>> str(s.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
'asd\n\nqwe'
```

To remove empty lines I'd use `re.sub('\n+', '\n', s)`.

Comment: You forgot to test `'asd\n123\xaa\xfa\xaf123\nqwe'` where your version yields the wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in fin:
    try:
        fout.write(line.encode('ASCII'))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
```

Comment: @glglgl, of course you are right and in fact that's what I used in testing my answer. Somehow it got lost in translation.

Answer (score 2):

In practice you'll want to *do* something with the data, and need to parse it further. If your file `test` looks like

```
http://example.com dog
http://example.com/√•%20√§%20√∂/ foo
http://google.com bar
```

A `pyparsing` script would remove the bad lines like so

```
from pyparsing import *

ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t")
EOL = LineEnd()
ascii  = u''.join(unichr(x) for x in xrange(33,127))
words  = Word(ascii)
good_line = Group(ZeroOrMore(words) + EOL)
bad_line  = SkipTo(EOL,include=True)

blocks = good_line | bad_line.suppress()
grammar = ZeroOrMore(blocks) + StringEnd()

P = grammar.parseFile("test")
print P
```

Which would give as output:

```
[['http://example.com', 'dog', '\n'], ['http://google.com', 'bar']]
```

The advantage to the other methods (which work fine, and answer the question), as that you now have a nice parse tree to further manipulate the data. The idea is to write a *grammar*, not a parser, for any task that has the potential to become more complicated then when first started.

Answer (score 1):

```
LC_ALL=C grep -v $'[^\t\r -~]'
```

`grep -v` prints all lines that *don't* match the pattern. `LC_ALL=C` sets the locale to "C". `$'[^\t\r -~]'` is a pattern that, in the C locale, means "contains a character that is not a horizontal tab, a line-feed, a space, or an ASCII glyphic character". (`$'...'` is a Bash notation: it's equivalent to `'...'`, except that it processes backslash-escapes like `\t` and `\r`. `[^...]` is a "negative character class", meaning "any character that isn't listed in `...`. Inside a character class, `-` matches a range: in this case, the range from space to tilde. The C locale is necessary to make sense of this "range".)